# QUERY function, containing string in the WHERE clause

Tags: string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, where-clause, google-query-language

I would like to copy and paste data from cells in columns A:D in sheet 1, onto sheet 2 only if the cells in Column F = yes

I have tried to write the formula, but I keep getting parse errors. The formula I have tried to use is

```
=query("Sheet1"!A:D,"Select A where F="Yes"")
```

Comment: i am not asking anyone to do my work for me.  i have tried to write the formula and keep getting Parse errors..  the formula i have tried to use is =query("Sheet1"!A:D,"Select A where F="Yes"")

Comment: column F is also on sheet 1, so i only want to paste over to "sheet 2" cells A:D if "sheet 1F" = "yes"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your code was not working, because you did not include F in your data range, when you first defined it. And also the double quotes problem around `Yes` - there should be single quotes. This works for me:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:F,"Select A Where F='Yes'")
```

In case you want to return 4 columns:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:F,"Select A, B, C, D Where F='Yes'")
```

Also worth noting - the string search in the `where` clause of the `query` function works only if in the column you have more strings than any of the other formats.